# How to get a reference to the list of a Flex List in Mouse Down event

Tags: list, apache-flex, mxml, mousedown

I have a list in mxml. I need to show a menu when the user longpresses an item in the list. The menu will show some action on the item that has been pressed on.

I also have to make the pressed item the selected item in the list. So I need a reference to the list. I cannot find a normal way to get to the list so I did this:

```
var list:Object = event.currentTarget.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent
```

Which of course is hideous. I am looking for a better way to get a reference to the list.

Here is my code for the list:

```
<s:List id="catList" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" click="selectItemHandler(event)">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:IconItemRenderer 
                styleName="labelFontStyle"
                messageStyleName="descriptionFontStyle"
                labelField="labelField"
                messageField="descriptionField"
                dataChange="onDataChange(event)"
                mouseDown="onMouseDown(event)">
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
                        protected function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                var tg:Object = event.target;
                                var selectedItem:Object = event.currentTarget.data;
                                if (selectedItem != null)
                                {
                                    // Here I need to set the selectedItem property of 
                                    // the owning list. 
                                    // I don't know how to get to the list so I did this.
                                    var list:Object = event.currentTarget.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent;
                                    list.selectedItem = selectedItem;   
                                }
                            } catch (e:Error) {}
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>                
            </s:IconItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>   
</s:List>
```

Comment: Is the list the top object in your mxml file?

Comment: @CyanAngel, The root object is a View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but won't just set the selected property in the itemrenderer's onMouseDown do the trick ?

```
selected = true;
```

If not, check if this will get you your list:

```
var myList:List = owner as List;
```

Another approach would be to create a custom event that contains your item and fire it from the itemrenderer. Then listen for that event on the list and set the selectedItem property to the item you got in the event